# Как объединить несколько столбцов в один и удалить дубликаты mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Как объединить несколько столбцов в один и удалить дубликаты mysql?
Вот примерный код:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT CONCAT(channeltv,',',channeltv2,',',channeltv3,',',channeltv4) as output FROM igry");
while ( $itemm = @mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) : 
echo $itemm['output'];
endwhile;
```

В результате получаю примерно такую строку:
канал1,канал3,канал10,канал12канал1,,,канал5,,канал1,канал10 итд...

тоесть все в одну строку, выводится запятая если ячейка пустая и выводятся дубли.

А нужно что было так:

канал1

канал3

канал5

канал10

канал12

итд...

Как правильно написать такой код?

Comment: `select channeltv from igry UNION select channeltv2 from igry ...` А вообще надо смотреть в сторону изменения структуры БД. хранить несколько значений одной природы колонками в одной записи не принято

Comment: изменять таблицу не вариант, нужно именно так

Comment: а можете полностью запрос написать с UNION, а то не совсем понимаю как получить конечный результать

Comment: ну вы тот что написал посмотрите для начала устраивает вывод или нет, а то вдруг я не так понял. А потом дописывайте еще union для каждого столбца

Comment: я не пойму как их вывести в конце в один столбец, сейчас там выводится echo $itemm['output'];, а как с вашим кодом будет?

Comment: точно так же. print_r посмотрите что у вас в массиве и выводите нужный столбец. думаю что он называется channeltv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кому будет интересно нашел решение на эту задачу, может и коряво, но работает

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT channeltv as output FROM igry
UNION (SELECT channeltv2 as output FROM igry)
UNION (SELECT channeltv3 as output FROM igry)
UNION (SELECT channeltv4  as output FROM igry) ORDER BY output");
echo '<select>';
while ( $itemm = @mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) : 
echo '<option>'.$itemm['output'].'</option>';
endwhile;
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, лучше сделать все это одной строчкой в PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT CONCAT(channeltv,',',channeltv2,',',channeltv3,',',channeltv4) as output FROM igry");
while ( $itemm = @mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) : 
echo implode("\n", array_unique(array_filter(explode(',', $itemm['output'])))); <---  тут было echo $itemm['output'];
endwhile;
```

Comment: а с дублями как быть? они этим кодом не уберутся

Comment: Дубли удалятся - для этого там стоит вызов функции array_unique